# NSDateFormatter with format string outputs time with short style

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

We have an iOS app in production and we use some custom format for our date internal representation.

I stored a global date formatter like this:

```
static var InternalDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HH':'mm"
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

With a `NSDate` instance of `2016-07-21T16:46:51+0000` the expected output is `20160721 16:46`, but in 2 phones the output is `20160712 4:41 p.m.`.

The device is an iPhone 5 with iOS 9.3.
I tried installing in a device, same model and same iOS version, and the output was right.

Could someone give me a glimpse into what's happening there?

Comment: that's strange. have you tried deleting your derived data and rebuilding the project onto the affected device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `timezone` and `locale` to your date formatter, try it like this:

```
static var InternalDateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = {
    let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd HH':'mm"
    dateFormatter.timeZone   = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    dateFormatter.locale     = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    return dateFormatter
}()
```

Using `en_US_POSIX` locale ID will always give you `am-pm` US time standard.
But you can choose any locale ID - https://gist.github.com/jacobbubu/1836273

Comment: NSDateFormatter's timeZone property is the system's time zone by default